# How to average across multiple regressions, correct for p-value and estimates?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, p-value, bias-correction

In this data frame I have 2 replicates that were placed in low, mid, or high areas with recorded densities at x and y. Within a certain level e.g. rep 1 "mid" has x = 24 and y = NAs. Biologically, it makes sense for me to also compare 24 against 10 (i.e. within the same level).

Edit in reply to comments: For each level, within each replicate I set up atleast 2 replicates of x and y. Therefore, replicate 1 of x can be compared with replicate 1 of y, or replicate 2 of y and vice-versa.

```
replicate level  x           y
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          10
    1     mid    24          NA
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2     mid    NA          24
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    NA           5
    2      up    20           2
```

Using this, I created multiple data-sets with no NAs like :

```
replicate level   x           y
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    82          10
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    20           2
```

Next data-set make one change and keep the rest same.

```
replicate level  x           y
    1     low    14          36
    1     low    54          31
    1     mid    24          10 #Pair 24 with 10 instead of NA
    2     low    12          28
    2     low    11          45
    2     mid    12          17
    2      up    40          10
    2      up    20           2
```

I do all permutation/ combinations of this and estimated glm regression for each run like this
[image]

Now, I want to compute the average of these regressions to get the best estimate of the fit and a confidence interval. Any suggestions on best method to go about this?

Comment: How exactly are you splitting up your data into the various regressions you are running?

Comment: @stats_model I have edited the answer to show the types of data set

Comment: There appear to be three *different* fits.  Are you sure that averaging them would even be meaningful?  And if so, how should they be weighted?  (The answer to that depends on your assumptions and on how you collected the data, neither of which are yet in evidence.)

Comment: Are you interested in the association between $y$ and $x$? If so, then you can control for level and replicate in your regression (i.e., do one multiple linear regression).

Comment: @whuber For each level, within each replicate I set up atleast 2 replicates of x and y. Therefore, replicate 1 of x can be compared with replicate 1 of y, or replicate 2 of y and vice-versa. Therefore average would be meanigful. I don't think weighting is needed

Comment: @philbo_baggins Yes, I am. I don't want to control for replicate and level because of the way the study is set-up. The goal here is to capture spatial variation.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to perform a multiple imputation of the missing values?

Comment: @whuber I had to look up the term but yes conceptually it appears to be quite similar to what I'm trying to achieve here. Although, I am not sure how to do it here

Comment: A good entry point is the `mice` package for `R` and its documentation.